# How does the Shot on the Run feat work with a rogue's stealth skill?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, rogue, stealth, ranged-attack

Specifically, the Fast Stealth rogue talent. In the core rulebook, it says it is impossible to use stealth while attacking, and that generally stealth checks are made during movement. I want to know if stealth will apply after my Shot on the Run attack without having to apply the -20 sniper penalty or the -10 penalty for cover to cover.

Also, what order would I roll for things and such in a situation where I'm moving from cover to cover in such a way? Is any of this even possible to begin with or am I getting way ahead of myself? I am trying to go with a sneaky archer.

Comment: Related: [Could I make a sneak attack, move behind new cover and make a stealth check?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/35272/9625).  Stealth in Pathfinder is wonky :(

Answer (score 2):

You can roll your stealth check everytime you have total cover or total concealment (the opponent doesn't know where you are).
That said, if you finish your movement after a *Shot on the Run* with full concealment (inside an area of darkness, behind a wall, turned invisible, etc), you are effectively stealthed.

**Sniping** is talking about remaining behind total cover, attack while stealthed, and hide again in total cover. If you succeed, nobody noticed where the arrows came from, if you fail, they have seen you firing them and they know you are there (but you still have total cover).

If you attempt to use *Shot on the Run* to run from cover to cover, fire, and still remaine unnoticed, you are **not Sniping**. *Shot on the Run* is a full-round action, while *Sniping* is a move action (the attack itself being a standard action).
So, during a *Shot on the Run*, you will be noticed, but since you hid behind total cover, you have total concealment against them, they simply will know which cover you are hiding at and can attempt to find you.